# Fill text field after upload image with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a upload button in my form and a image url text field, user can type url manually or upload image by button, like this:
[image]

i trying to fill url field whit image when user upload by button but my code doesn't work, I do not have experience with javascript.

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="example-url-input" class="col-sm-1 col-form-label">URL</label>
    <label for="upload-btn" class="btn btn-primary btn-file">Upload</label>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
      <input class="form-control" type="url" id="example-url-input">
      <input type="file" class="hidden" id="upload-btn" onchange='$("example-url-input").html($(this).val());'>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Please explain your exact issue , i can not understand

Comment: Url?Path to his local machine?

Comment: I would recommend you tag `jQuery` in your question since you're trying to use `jQuery`. I am also finding it hard to understand what it is you're trying to do and that the problem is. Are you trying ti display a preview of the image or display the string/text path/source? Show the image once it has uploaded? How are you uploading the image?

Comment: Are you trying to upload a image with URL provided by user?

Comment: FYI `$("example-url-input").html($(this).val());` is missing `#` and should be `val()` not `html()`. It should be `$("#example-url-input").val($(this).val());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this way

```
 onchange = 'document.getElementById("example-url-input").value=document.getElementById("upload-btn").value'
```